# Unable to post message into yammer forum

Tags: office365, yammer

Unable to post message into yammer forum via web app, it stopped working from today onwards and we see the following error in the network console.

https://www.yammer.com/api/v1/network_deprecations?network_id=282811&_=1576519679171

> https://www.yammer.com/api/v1/yamalytics/webui { code: 405, message:
>   "HTTP 405 Method Not Allowed" }

Comment: You should open a support case with Microsoft Support so this can be investigated. A support case can be opened from the O365 Admin Portal.

Comment: We are not a Microsoft customer yet and finding it hard to get any support for this issue. Don't have access to Office 365 as well from the primary account